# Cómo conectar MSSQL a Visual Code (con Node.js)

Tags: nodejs, mssql

He probado de varias formas, entre ellas las que se muestran aquí:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/node/windows/step/2.html

(son más o menos lo mismo)

Y me da este error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOP-xxxxxSQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND LAPTOP-xxxxxSQLEXPRESS
> code: 'ESOCKET'

---

Mi código:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

// Create connection to database
var config = {
  server: 'LAPTOP-xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS',
  authentication: {
      type: 'default',
      options: {
          userName: 'xxxx', // update me
          password: 'xxxx', // update me
      }
  },
  options: {
      database: 'SampleDB'
  }
}
var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected');
  }
});

connection.connect();
```

También he cambiado el puerto TCP a 1433 para que coincida con el que está por defecto pero da el mismo error.

---

Otra forma:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

try {
    sql.connect('mssql://xxxx:xxxx@LAPTOP-xxxx\SQLEXPRESS/GDP?encrypt=true')
    console.log('Se ha conectado a la base de datos')
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}

export default sql;
```

Y su error:

> tedious deprecated The default value for `config.options.enableArithAbort` will change from `false` to `true` in the next major version of `tedious`. Set the value to `true` or `false` explicitly to silence this message. node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23
>
> (node:31776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> (node:31776) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: El valor que usas para la opción `server` no es correcto. Entiendo que la documentación no aporta mucho al respecto, pero para conectarte a una instancia con nombre debes añadirla como un campo llamado `instanceName` dentro del campo `options`. Tal como se documenta [aquí](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/20). Intenta eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: También puedes acudir directamente a la [documentación](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_newConnection) de la API para las opciones de conexión. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras he cambiado el nombre del `server ` a `server: 'LAPTOP-xxxxx'` y he añadido en `options`: `instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'`. El nuevo error ahora es:  ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOP-xxxx\SQLEXPRESS in 15000ms. code: 'ETIMEOUT'.

Comment: @MauricioContreras He visto que tengo el SQL Server Browser detenido, fallo seguramente un poco básico pero tampoco consigo que se inicie. Me da "Error en la solicitud o el servicio no respondió a tiempo".

Comment: Has probado usando la dirección IP de ese equipo?

Comment: @MauricioContreras He conseguido arrancar el SQL Server Browser y poniendo la `instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'` el error cambia a: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOP-xxxx:undefined - Could not connect (sequence). code: 'ESOCKET'. También he probado poniendo mi IP `localAddress: 'x.x.x.x'` y da el mismo error.

Comment: No, hablo de poner `server: 'WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ',` Como servidor pasas la IP del equipo que tiene SQL Server, por otro lado, ¿te has asegurado que el Firewall permite conexiones hacia el puerto 1433 de SQL Server? Es un error muy común no abrir el puerto, bien sea en el Firewall y/o antivirus. Además, hay que configurar la conexión TCP del Servidor. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Acabo de hacerlo en el antivirus y sale lo mismo. ¿Lo de configurar la conexión TCP del servidor es poner en IpAll, Puerto TCP: 1433 en el Sql Server Configuration Manager? Si es eso sí lo he hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar sequelize

```
npm install --save sequelize
npm install --save tedious // MSSQL


const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql',
})
```

para verificar si la conexión funciona usa el método authenticate()

```
sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Conectado')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('No se conecto')
  })
```

En este articulo podes ver el paso a paso

> https://ed.team/blog/agiliza-tu-desarrollo-en-nodejs-con-el-orm-sequelize